# Show the exact time below date

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have this code for showing the date of my posts.

```
<time datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-j'); ?>" title="<?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>">
    <span class="post-date"><?php the_time('d'); ?></span>
    <span class="post-month uppercase"><?php the_time('F'); ?></span>
</time>
```

I would like to add the exact time of when I posted the post.
As seen on Wordpress forum, I tried to add the code below (which worked for some people)

```
<?php the_time('g:i a'); ?>
```

next to

```
<?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>
```

but the time was still not showing.
Could you please tell me why it's not working for me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time isn't being shown because you added it to the title attribute of the time element rather than inside the element.

To show the time, add it beneath the `.post-month` span tag.

E.g.

```
. . . 
<span class="post-month uppercase"><?php the_time('F'); ?></span>
<span class="post-time"><?php the_time( 'g:i a' ); ?></span>
. . .
```